# Update query is not working - help needed

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, ms-access

```
private void Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string loca="Pakistan";

    OleDbConnection con = new   OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Usman\\Desktop\\db.accdb");

    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("Update INVENTORY SET Location=? WHERE itemID='1' ", con);
    com.Parameters.Add("@loca", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = loca;

    con.Open();

    try
    {
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch(Exception f)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(f.Message);
        //MessageBox.Show("Given Data is not Valid", "Cannot Add", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    con.Close();

    gridview();
}
```

Here I have changed the code no error m getting is

> No value given for one or more required parameters

Update query is not working so please help me with it.

Comment: You're not adding the `@loca` parameter.

Comment: And I don't *think* OleDbCommand supports named parameters anyway.

Comment: @juharr its added i guess

Comment: @JonSkeet then what exactly i need to do?

Comment: No, you have to create an `OleDbParameter` and add it to the `OleDbCommand.Parameters` collection.  And as Jon said, you probably need to replace `@loca` with `?`.

Comment: Look at the [`OleDbCommand.Parameters` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters) for a start.

Comment: @juharr can u give example please?

Comment: By the way, based on it's name, `itemID` shouldn't be a numeric typed column? Like; `itemID = 1`?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman What is the data type (and size) of `Location` in the database?

Comment: @DStanley short text

Answer (score 3):

In C# you need to add an actual parameter object and give it a value:

```
string loca="Pakistan";
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Usman\\Desktop\\db.accdb");

OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("Update INVENTORY SET Location= ? WHERE itemID='1'", con);
com.Parameters.Add("@loca", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = loca ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
```

Some other suggestions/habits to get in to:

- Wrap your connections and commands in `using` blocks so that they get disposed of in a timely manner
- Do not just catch an exception and show a vague message.  Either include the exception details or log it somewhere so that you know what the *actual* error is.

Comment: Except that as noted in comments, `OleDbCommand` doesn't support named parameters, and I suspect you need to use `OleDbType`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Are you sure _doesn't support_ is completely right here? As far as I know, it _actually_ **does** support named parameters but it just doesn't _care_ them. _Only_ care about their orders. MSDN documentation is kind of wrong about this subject. Using `?` is not _have to_ either.

Comment: tried what u suggested removed try catch now it stop debugging at 
   executenonQuuery

Comment: @MuhammadUsman If `ExecuteNonQuery` is throwing an exception you need to include the error message in your question.

Comment: @JonSkeet still cannot Update

Comment: @juharr after adding exception it says " no value given for one or more required parameters "?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman That sounds like the error you would get before making the changes Stanley has suggested.  Perhaps you should update your question will what you are doing now and the error message.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks - fixed the enum type.  You can give parameters a name when adding them to the command, just not in the SQL.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Did you change the SQL to use `?` instead of `@loca`?

Comment: @DStanley yes it is changed..let me show my updated code

Comment: @DStanley still same :(

Comment: @MuhammadUsman The only thing I can see that would cause that error is if `loca` were null, which it obviously isn't in your example (unless you're running different code than what you've posted).

Comment: @MuhammadUsman To be safe I added a null-check to prevent that error - it would just update the field to NULL in the database.

Comment: @SonerGönül: Sorry for not responding earlier. I'd say that if the name is ignored, it doesn't *really* support named parameters - and I would avoid specifying a name when it's not going to be used... it's just inviting someone  to reorder the parameter additions and cause problems.

Comment: @JonSkeet then what should i do?

Comment: Use `?` in the SQL query, and then probably just use `p0`, `p1` etc when specifying the names when you add the parameters.